# SQL - Aggregation based on a parameter

Tags: sql

I have a following table -

```
Play_Code    County_and_city  Q_Flag  Country
A1           County1_Denver    0       USA 
A2           County2_Denver    1       USA
A3           County3_Denver    0       USA
B1           County1_Dallas    0       USA
B2           County2_Dallas    0       USA
```

I want Q_Flag  of all records of same city to be 1 if even one record is having Q_Flag as 1 for the same city. If none of the record for a city is having 1 then they all should remain as 0 only
So the result of above table should be like below -

```
Play_Code    County_and_city  Q_Flag  Country
A1           County1_Denver    1       USA 
A2           County2_Denver    1       USA
A3           County3_Denver    1       USA
B1           County1_Dallas    0       USA
B2           County2_Dallas    0       USA
```

One way I think is to create a separate table by doing a max condition on Q_Flag and then join it with original table. But is there way to do it within the same table using SQL?

Comment: Which dbms is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using mysql, we need to group our data by city then using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to extract city from column `County_and_city`, then we check if at least one Q_flag = 1.

```
    select t.Play_Code, t.County_and_city, s.Q_Flag, t.Country
    from mytable t
    inner join (
      select SUBSTRING_INDEX(County_and_city, '_', -1) as city,
case when sum(Q_Flag) >=1 then 1 else 0 end as Q_flag
      from mytable
      group by SUBSTRING_INDEX(County_and_city, '_', -1)
    ) as s on t.County_and_city like concat('%', s.city)
```

Assuming `County_and_city` contains city only then :

```
select t.Play_Code, t.County_and_city, s.Q_Flag, t.Country
from mytable t
inner join (
  select County_and_city as city, case when sum(Q_Flag) >=1 then 1 else 0 end as Q_flag
  from mytable
  group by County_and_city
) as s on t.County_and_city = s.city
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SztBwOqw)

Comment: substring_index, even if this would be mysql or mariadb, is a costly function and absolutely not necessary

Comment: Yes true its costly, do you have any better solution to extract the city ?

Comment: there is no need to ectract the city, as the wanted result doesn't show that he  wants the city name, also what gappens if there are two with one or even more, so the sum woulde not show the correct number, as this question is unclear, it should be closed

Comment: The extracted city is needed to group data with, and the sum is used here to check if at least one Q_flag equal 1 then all should be 1.

Comment: Lets assume city is available then what is the solution. Assume County_and_city as City please

Comment: @jarlh I have already mentioned mysql in my answer